# What's the difference between "Mark for Removal" and "Mark for Complete Removal" in Synaptic Package Manager?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, package-management, synaptic-pkg-mgr

When I right click on a package in Synaptic Package Manager it presents selections for removal and complete removal. What are the differences between these options?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Mark for removal** removes the package, but not the configuration files associated with the package. It is equivalent to

```
apt-get remove package_name
```

**Mark for Complete Removal** purges the package, i.e. removes both the package files and its configuration. It is equivalent to

```
apt-get --purge remove package_name
```

From the Synaptic Package Manager manual:

> **3.2. To Remove Packages**
>
> Configuration files and user created
>   data (e.g. a website in "/var/www")
>   are not removed from the system by
>   default.
>
> *Debian only*: You can change the default behavior in the preferences.
>
> *Debian only*: To remove all files
>   related to the package choose Mark for
>   Complete Removal instead of Mark for
>   Removal.

Answer (score 1):

The "complete removal" option will also remove global configurations files, e.g. in `/etc`